# How to create a non-generic Func as a placeholder

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a problem where I need to generate placeholders for a Func so that it is defined before a switch statement. The thing is, it will be assigned to functions that have different signatures.

What I wanted is something like the following (which is not working):

```
Func<> labelChecker = null;
Func<> NumericStarter = null;

switch (someCondition) {
      case 1:
           labelChecker = Proxy.CheckCompoundLabel;
           numericStarter = Proxy.StartCompoundNumeric;
           break;
      case 2:
           labelChecker = Proxy.CheckNativeLabel;
           numericStarter = Proxy.StartNativeNumeric;
           break;
      case 3:
           labelChecker = Proxy.CheckCustomLabel;
           numericStarter = Proxy.StartCustomNumeric;
           break;

labelChecker.Invoke(...)
numericStarter.Invoke(...)
```

By doing this, I can invoke `labelChecker` and `numericStarter` out of the switch statement. What may help is that all the Proxy methods I wanted to use here has the same return value `int`, but the input arguments are different. Is what I want here possible?

Comment: why not using Func<dynamic, int> or Func<object, int> ?

Comment: If the input arguments are different, how would you know at the end which arguments you need to supply to the invoke statement?

Comment: @Lei The problem is that the number of required input arguments are different, CheckCompoundLabel has 2 while CheckNativeLabel and CheckCustomLabel has 4. Is it still possible somehow?

Comment: @aldo an object array is still an object, and you can use 'params' ----delegate void Method(string s, params object[] args);

Answer (score 0):

**Known parameter length**

If you know the number of parameters you could just use a more abstract type. For example, an interface that your parameters implement.
Or alternatively an `object`.

```
Func<object>? labelChecker = null;
Func<object>? NumericStarter = null;
```

**Unknown parameter length**

If it is not in a hot path you could use a `dynamic`.
Please use this only if you are 100% sure that you don't care about performance.

A dynamic makes the program much slower ([see what Roslyn generates when lowering dynamics](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQzABCBMEMIQN4FgBQENUgSwHYBcIBBAExIBUBPABwFMSAKPQgQwBoJmIAjASiTSYhUAOwQWEANQ8A3IMwBfeRmVYIJSrhYBbbAGNiZACKad+hhq26D7daes9+KdMIwgxE6dzkuMS1ApAA)).

```
dynamic labelChecker = null;
dynamic NumericStarter = null;
```